# Multiple HttpPost Method in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

I could not head around on my routing rules in ASP.NET Core. I have following Back and Front-end application of user authentication action methods. Since both of these action methods has one parameter with different or additional arguments in payload. Http client could not actually navigate exact method therefore throw an exception with an error "ambiguity" and it is true because both these HttpPost method has one parameter with different arguments. How to make sure that method triggers according to action. Code follows :-

API Controller:-

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")]
  public class AccountController: Controller
  {
         [HttpPost, ActionName("Login")]
         public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user)
         {
            //Code goes here
         }

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Register")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UserRegistration(RegisterDto register)
        {
             //Code goes here
        }
  }
```

Frontend API Service

```
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetLoginAsync(LoginDto loginUser)
   {
                var request = "/api/account";
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginUser), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                try
                {
                    var result = await ExecuteWithResiliencePolicies(() => _client.PostAsync(request, content));
                    return new StatusCodeResult((int)result.StatusCode);

                }
                catch (HttpRequestException)
                {
                    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable);
                }           
     }

     public async Task<IActionResult> PostRegistrationAsync(RegisterDto registerUser)
     {
                var request = "/api/account";
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(registerUser), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                try
                {
                    var result = await ExecuteWithResiliencePolicies(() => _client.PostAsync(request, content));
                    return new StatusCodeResult((int)result.StatusCode);

                }
                catch (HttpRequestException)
                {
                    return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status503ServiceUnavailable);
                }
      }
```

Web Controller :-

```
     [HttpPost, ActionName("Login")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user)
            {
                SetCorrelation();
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
                }
                await _accountService.GetLoginAsync(user);              
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            [HttpPost, ActionName("Register")]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            public async Task<IActionResult> UserRegistration(RegisterDto register)
            {
                SetCorrelation();
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Login));
                }
                await _accountService.PostRegistrationAsync(register);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");


}
```

Web Routing :

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "WebRoute",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" },
                    constraints: new { id = "[0-9]+" });                
            });
```

API Routing:-

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "KtsWebAPIRoute",
                    template: "{controller=Posts}/{action=GetAsync}/{id?}");

                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "KtsAccountRoute",
                    template: "{controller}/{action}/{id?}",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Account", Action = "Login" },
                    constraints: new { id = "[0-9]+" });
            });
```

Comment: In your frontend API service, have you tried using request urls `/api/account/Login` and `/api/account/Register`?

Comment: Yeah i already tried that and it's throw an error 404.

Comment: Try applying `Route` attribute to your api controller instead of ActionName e.g. `[Route("login")]public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user)`

Answer (score 10):

There are couple of possible solutions. For every solution front-end part should call the following urls

```
"/api/account/login"
"/api/account/register"
```

**Solution 1**

You need to specify template in `HttpPost` attribute ASP.NET Core routing cannot get action name from request

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user) { /*..*/ }
}
```

or you can combine template with `ActionName`

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost("[action]"), ActionName("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user) { /*..*/ }
}
```

**Solution 2**

Update route for controller to include action name as well

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user) { /*..*/ }
}
```

**Solution 3**

Use `Route` attributes for actions

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost, Route("Login")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserLogin(LoginDto user) { /*..*/ }
}
```

Comment: i have tried what you have suggested but unfortunately did not work out. Getting 400 (Bad Request) but api did not throw any exception however httpclient throw this error. I will try some more research let's see. BTW Thanks for you help..

Comment: @Urgen Well, you now have 400 error instead of 404, so action was found. Try debugging action method to see if it was hit. Also you may try adding `[FromBody]` before action parameter `UserLogin([FromBody]LoginDto user)`

Comment: @Urgen And if you are using `HttpClient` the request string must be valid `Uri` and contain `http://server/api/..`

Answer (score 3):

Use `ApiController` attribute and `ControllerBase`:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...
}
```

and the URL should look like this

```
var url = "............/api/Account/Login";
```